# WiX Installer: Using xslt with heat.exe how do I find a matching substring when also using a match attribute?

Tags: xslt, wix, substring, heat

I have the following source:

```
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
        <Component Id="Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate_acuthin.exe" Guid="*" Win64="no">
            <File Id="Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate_acuthin.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.HARVESTDIR)\Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate\acuthin.exe" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

I have the following template that finds all DirectoryRef that have an Id of 'INSTALLDIR' and have a Component that has an Id of 'Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate_acuthin.exe' and changes the DirectoryRef Id from 'INSTALLDIR' to 'TARGETDIR':

```
  <xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef[@Id='INSTALLDIR' and wix:Component/@Id='Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate_acuthin.exe']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">TARGETDIR</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Here is the correct result:

```
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Component Id="Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate_acuthin.exe" Guid="*" Win64="no">
            <File Id="Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate_acuthin.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.HARVESTDIR)\Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate\acuthin.exe" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

If my source has several DirectoryRefs with Component Id's that look like this:

```
<Component Id="Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate_acuthin.exe" Guid="*" Win64="no">
<Component Id="Groupfile1.exeAutoUpdate_file1.exe" Guid="*" Win64="no">
<Component Id="Groupfile2.exeAutoUpdate_file2.exe" Guid="*" Win64="no">
```

Is there a way to change the template to match any Component that has an Id where the Id contains the substring 'AutoUpdate'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contains` function in the template matching rule:

```
<xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef[@Id='INSTALLDIR' and contains(wix:Component/@Id,'AutoUpdate')]">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

Then all of your samples will match.

---

> Is there a way to change the template to match any Component that has an Id where the Id contains the substring 'AutoUpdate'?

To do that, use the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="wix:Component[contains(@Id,'AutoUpdate')]">
  <xsl:element name="Component">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Without the *Identity template*, the result would be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Component Id="Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate_acuthin.exe" Guid="*" Win64="no"/>
<Component Id="Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate_acuthin.exe" Guid="*" Win64="no"/>
<Component Id="Groupfile1.exeAutoUpdate_file1.exe" Guid="*" Win64="no"/>
<Component Id="Groupfile2.exeAutoUpdate_file2.exe" Guid="*" Win64="no"/>
```

Comment: I tried the contains() but it does not seem to find the substring with AutoUpdate. It just outputs what was in the source and INSTALLDIR does not get changed to TARGETDIR.  Any ideas why it does not find the AutoUpdate substring?